# Run and execute a file in Ubuntu Virtualbox

Tags: ubuntu, virtual-machine, virtualbox

I'm using Ubuntu on Virtualbox. When I double-click the .sh file, the option to execute it doesn't come up? I'm very new to Ubuntu and I don't know any of the other ways to get a file to execute. I've tried to use the terminal, but I'm not exactly sure if i did it right. Can anyone tell me how to execute the file?

[image]

[image]

Comment: This really belongs on superuser.com or the ubuntu forums, not on a programming site.

Comment: This Q is not about programming as defined for StackOverflow. It may be more appropriate on the related site askubuntu.com. Consider using the flag link at the bottom of your Q and ask the moderator to move it there. Good luck.

Comment: Run `chmod u+x setup.sh` to make the file executable by owner, or `chmod a+x setup.sh` to make it executable by everyone.

Answer (score 0):

Please add the execute permission for owner atleast. Rightnow owner has read and write permission  only. what you can do is chmod 744 or 766. on the sh file

Answer (score 0):

Are you receiving any error messages or does nothing happen at all? To run a file like this you require executable permissions.

Using the terminal, you can run the following command on the file:

```
chmod 744 setup.sh

7 - gives the owner full read (4), write (2) and execute (1) permissions i.e. 4+2+1=7
4 - gives the group read permissions
4 - gives everyone else read permissions
```

Comment: I've tried that but when i type chmod 744 setup.sh in the terminal ' chmod: cannot access 'setup.sh' : no such file or directory' https://i.imgur.com/wpfXpCm.png

Comment: This exact command will only work in the terminal when you change your current location to the same location as setup.sh, from your screenshot that location appears to be /home/zez75/Desktop. Therefore in the terminal you need to type **cd /home/zez75/Desktop**  . 'cd' stands for change directory. Next if you type **ls -l** you will see a long list of the files currently on the Desktop. You should hopefully see your setup.sh file among the list and its current permissions. Type **chmod 744 setup.sh** to modify the permissions as per my previous answer. And that should do it.

Comment: https://i.imgur.com/Ejdohbo.png I've done this but now when i double click the file still no option to execute it comes up, it only opens it and shows me whats inside. I feel like I'm missing something obvious, i just want to run the file as a sh file

Comment: After you have used the cd command to navigate to the current location of the sh file (Desktop), type either one of the following three ways to run a sh file which has been given executable permissions: 1) **./setup.sh**   2) **. setup.sh**  3)  **sh setup.sh**